# problem allocating string operation to variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am trying to write a script to go through a set of file names removing the dashes and white spaces, and then add a suffix before the file extension. Here is the set of files:

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/matlab/chiroping/workspace/myFunctions/labellings/Panama20090322new$ ls Me*
Measurements 2009-03-22 Session6.xml          Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session4.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session10.xml  Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session5.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session1.xml   Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session6.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session2.xml   Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session7.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session3.xml   Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session8.xml
```

So here is the script that goes through the set of files, removes the dashes and white space, but it is as if variable "var2" does not get reset to the expression below. It is initially set to "tempSTR" and remains so.

```
 alex@alex-laptop:~/matlab/chiroping/workspace/myFunctions/labellings/Panama20090322new$ for f in Me*; 
do var1=${f//[ -]/}; var2= echo -n $var1 | cut -f1 -d '.'; 
suffix="new"; var3= echo $var2;  done
    Measurements20090322Session6
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session10
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session1
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session2
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session3
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session4
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session5
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session6
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session7
    tempSTR
    MeasurementsPanama20090322Session8
    tempSTR
```

I think that there is something wrong with this line

```
 var2= echo -n $var1 | cut -f1 -d '.';
```

when trying to set var2 to the expression which prints out ok initially

Best,

Comment: Does `var= echo "a"` work in your bash? In mine it doesn't. var=``echo "a"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make any sense. Here's your script:

```
for f in Me* ; do
    var1=${f//[ -]/};
    var2= echo -n $var1 | cut -f1 -d '.'
    suffix="new"
    var3= echo $var2
done
```

You are declaring `var2` to be empty for the run of `echo -n`, and later `var3` to be empty for the run of `echo`, and you are declaring `suffix` to be "new", but you never use these variables. Perhaps you meant

```
for f in Me* ; do
    var1=${f//[ -]/};
    var2=$(echo -n $var1 | cut -f1 -d '.')
    suffix="new"
    var3=$(echo $var2)
done
```

But here you still never use `$suffix` or `$var3`. My best interpretation is that you meant to write.

```
suffix="new"
for f in Me* ; do
    var1=${f//[ -]/};
    echo -n $(echo $var1 | cut -f1 -d '.')
    echo -n $suffix.
    echo $var1 | cut -f2- -d '.'
done
```

But this still isn't a very logical way to do it when you could just say..

```
suffix=new
for f in Me* ; do
        f="${f//[ -]}"
        f="${f/./${suffix}.}"
        echo $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Python?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
directory = "/home/foo/bar"
for f in os.listdir(directory):
  if a[0:2] != "Me":
    continue
  parts = f.rsplit(".", 1)
  newname = parts[0].replace(" ", "").replace("-", "") + "." + parts[1]
  os.rename(f, newname)
```